# Open page as if Nav Element clicked?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a single page site that hides and shows elements depending on which nav element has been clicked.  Can anyone advise how to open this page as if one of the elements has been clicked already? I'm trying to put a link somewhere else that will open the page and show the 'gigs' element immediately.

The site is www.brookebentham.co.uk

Comment: Do you want this behavior to be triggered by the URL? If so you could check window.hash and use a URL like http://www.brookebentham.co.uk#gigs. Check window.hash == 'gigs'

Comment: Also look at the onhashchange event to support typing or pasting that URL after already loading the homepage.

Comment: Thanks Matt, you put me on the right path for the correct answer. I just used an if (window.location.hash == "gigs"){do what I need}.

Comment: You're welcome...and yes, that's right, it's `window.location.hash` not `window.hash` (or you could just use `location.hash`)

Answer (score 2):

use hashes

```
http://www.site.com/#tab/firstTab
```

then on page load or [onhashchange event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onhashchange), look at the hash and do something based on it

```
$(document).ready(hashChanged);
window.onhashchange = hashChanged;

function hashChanged() {
   var hash = window.location.hash;
   var tab = hash.replace("tab/","");
   $("#"+tab).show();
}
```

or you can use the [history.pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState%28%29.C2.A0method) (if supported) and just check the path

```
//assume something like as url http://www.site.com/tab/firstTab

//history has changed (ie on using pushSate)
window.onpopstate = function(){
   //path will be "/tab/firstTab"
   var path = window.location.pathname;
   var tab = path.replace("/tab/","");
   $("#"+tab).show();
};

$("#firstTab").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   history.pushState({},"Title (not really used","/tab/firstTab");
});
```

To fully use the pushState you would need the backend to do url rewriting, like apache's mod_rewrite to point all urls to your one page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(window).on("load", function(){
    $("#gig").show();
});
```